# Accidentally disconnected my Codechef account from Github

Tags: authentication, github

I am new to the Codechef platform registered using a Github account. For some reason, I wanted to log out. So I clicked on the Github symbol on Codechef page. My chrome browser asked 'are you sure you want to disconnect Github account?' and I have clicked 'OK'.

Now Codechef is asking for new registration. What to do?
Please help I don't want to lose all my work on Codechef.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer.
Open the login page of CodeChef. Enter the username of your account and use **Github password**.
You will get your account back. This account will not be linked with Github.

Note: If you forgot your username you can possibly find it in your registered(Github) email id's mail inbox.